# Is secure to use "createCipheriv" from "crypto" to ensure authenticity on a API call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, security, koa

### Context:

To contextualize I have an app (React Native) that will need to use a third-party login API (A E-commerce SASS platform), the said API will not allow me to use the returns from other than the same subdomain to redirect, my idea is to create a node.js service inside the platform with that I make my API endpoint check for a token generated from a unique key using createCipheriv, if it all matches return to the correct URL, note that this will not interfere in the login process, I just wish to secure the origin of the requests.

### The flow would be like so:

```
1. App + "?returnUrl={API}&token={...}"
2. Login + "&token={...}" + Redirect
3. API Check origin + Redirect
4. Return to App
```

### Just an example of the process:

Service:

```js
const { createCipheriv, randomBytes, createDecipheriv } = require('crypto');

/// Cipher
const message = "USER_EMAIL"; // Shared Info

const key = "SECRET_KEY"; // Shared secret
const iv = randomBytes(16); // Shared IV

const cipher = createCipheriv('aes256', key, iv);

/// Encrypt
const encryptedMessage = cipher.update(message, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');
```

Payload:

```js
{
  "token": "...",
  "iv": "..."
}
```

RN App:

```js
const { token, iv } = payload

const key = "SECRET_KEY"; // Shared secret

/// Decrypt
const decipher = createDecipheriv('aes256', key, iv);
const decryptedMessage = decipher.update(encryptedMessage, 'hex', 'utf-8') + decipher.final('utf8');

console.log(`Deciphered: ${decryptedMessage.toString('utf-8')}`);
```

Comment: It seems that only your service encrypts and decrypts the token. So what's the point of encryption? Why don't you simply generate a random, long enough token and get rid of cryptographic nuances?

Comment: Oh, ok I probably made myself misunderstood here, I will update the examples.